# Relaying multicast traffic between docker network and host network

Tags: python, docker, sockets, networking, multicast

I've been trying to multicast traffic between the docker network and the host network. Here's an example of my current setup, with docker containers in blue inside the purple docker network and host network PC's in orange inside the yellow host network:

[image: Text]

As you can see, I'm trying to capture and relay multicast traffic inside the 'Relay' docker container. I've given it the `--net host` option to make the host network interface (ens160) available to it. This allows me to capture traffic on both the docker interface (docker0) and the host interface, after which I resend the traffic over the opposite interface (traffic captured on docker interface gets resent using the host interface and vice versa).

This seems to work when I resend traffic from the docker network to the host network. But traffic from the host network does not want to get sent to the docker network. The green arrows represent successful multicast traffic flows, as in, I confirmed that multicast traffic is sent and received along the arrow. The red arrows show that multicast traffic is not being received on the arrow-ends. All the traffic is sent/received on the same port.

Here's some of the Python code of the relay program:

```
import socket, netifaces as ni
from scapy.all import sniff, Raw, IP, UDP

def pkt_found(other_sock, multicast_address, port, iface_ip):
    def save_pkt(pkt):
        if pkt[IP].src != iface_ip:
            pkt[IP].src = iface_ip
            pkt[IP].dst = multicast_address
            pkt[UDP].sport = port
            pkt[UDP].dport = port
            del pkt[IP].chksum
            pkt.show2()
            other_sock.sendto(bytes(pkt[Raw]), (multicast_address, port))
    return save_pkt

def listen_for_traffic(iface_name, other_sock, multicast_address, port, iface_ip):
    sniff(iface=iface_name, filter="dst port "+str(port), prn=pkt_found(other_sock, multicast_address, port, iface_ip))

def createMulticastSocket(iface_ip, multicast_address, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, 
    socket.inet_aton(multicast_address)+socket.inet_aton(iface_ip))
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 64)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, 0)
    sock.bind((multicast_address, port))
    return sock

multicast_address = "225.0.0.0"
port = 1234

docker_iface_name = "docker0"
host_iface_name = "ens160"

docker_iface_ip = ni.ifaddresses(docker_iface_name)[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
host_iface_ip = ni.ifaddresses(host_iface_name)[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']

docker_sock = createMulticastSocket(docker_iface_ip, multicast_address, port)
host_sock = createMulticastSocket(host_iface_ip, multicast_address, port)

docker_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_traffic, args=(docker_iface_name, host_sock, multicast_address, port, docker_iface_ip,))
host_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_traffic, args=(host_iface_name, docker_sock, multicast_address, port, host_iface_ip,))

docker_thread.start()
host_thread.start()
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I should have bound the sockets to the interface IPs instead. Changing  `sock.bind((multicast_address, port))` to `sock.bind((iface_ip, port))` did the trick.